# Apache qpid setDelay

Tags: c++, qpid

Does Apache qpid-cpp messaging api support delayed delivery of message as in ActiveMQ?

```
    TextMessage message = session.createTextMessage("test msg");
    long time = 60 * 1000;
    message.setLongProperty(ScheduledMessage.AMQ_SCHEDULED_DELAY, time);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this is not currently supported (current version is 0.10).  If you'd like to see this included in a future version, I would recommend creating a feature request in the [Qpid JIRA](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/QPID) if one doesn't exist yet.